# How to regroup a list of list based on keys in linear time?

Tags: python, list, loops, anagram

Hi I'm new to Python and I have a list of list

arr=[['act', 'abd'], ['cat', 'act'], ['tac', 'act'], ['bad', 'act'], ['fad', 'adf']]

I want to use arr[index][1] (in this case its 'act','abd', and 'adf') as the key to regroup my list of list to become like this in O(N) time where N is the input list:

```
arr=[['act','act','cat','tac'],['abd','bad'],['adf','fad']]
```

Here's what I tried but the output just doesn't make sense:

```
def groupList(a_list):
index=0
searchList=[]
while index<len(tempList)-1:
    key=tempList[index][1]
    newList=[]
    newList.append(key)
    newList.append(tempList[index][0])
    if tempList[index+1][1]==key:
        newList.append(tempList[index+1][0])
    else:
        searchList.append(newList)
    index+=1
print(searchList)
```

output is:

```
[['abd', 'act'], ['act', 'bad']]
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Why isn't the expected output `arr=[['act','act','act','act','cat','tac'],['abd','bad'],['adf','fad']]` ? Is it because the first `act` also points to `act` ?

Comment: @NickParsons True, I assumed the structure was `[key, value1, value2, ...]`. Confirmation would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it should be key,value,value etc. But somehow its not appending properly?

Comment: @SookLim Your code looks messy and is incomplete. `tempList` is not even defined. So yeah, you probably messed things up somewhere, but it's hard to tell where. You got 2 better solutions below. Try to understand them. Both are in O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than your code, I have this one:

```
arr= [['act', 'act'], ['cat', 'act'], ['tac', 'act'], ['bad', 'abd'],['fad', 'adf']] 

new_arr = []
keys = []

for elt in arr:
    if elt[1] not in keys:
        # apparently you want the key first
        new_arr.append([elt[1], elt[0]])
        keys.append(elt[1])
    else:
        id = keys.index(elt[1])
        new_arr[id].append(elt[0])
```

It's just looking if the key was already encountered or not, if it was it looks for where to place the new element.

Output:

```
new_arr
Out: [['act', 'act', 'cat', 'tac'], ['abd', 'bad'], ['adf', 'fad']]
```

However, this is not O(n) because of the `.index()` method and the `in`. It's O(n²).

N.B: I doubt this can be done in O(n) since you need a for loop to loop on the input, and for each element, you need to look if it needs to be placed in a new sublist or in an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the lists from your list of lists

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda l: l[-1]
>>> [[k]+[l[0] for l in v] for k,v in groupby(sorted(arr, key=f), f)]
[['abd', 'bad'], ['act', 'act', 'cat', 'tac'], ['adf', 'fad']]
```